# Does a GitHub account password change affect generated SSH keys?

Tags: github

I have a generated SSH key on my computer (Ubuntu *14.04*) with help from the [GitHub.com blog](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).

Now, if I change the password of my GitHub account (from same or other computer) do I then need to regenerate the SSH key, or it would work as it was before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your GitHub account password and SSH key(s) used to connect with repos hosted on GitHub are two different [set of credentials](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-your-github-access-credentials/).

You can change one without affecting the other.